# Unable to use [formControl] on a group of radiobuttons in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a list of groups of radiobuttons in Angular2. I want to bind the value of each group of radiobuttons using [formControl], however, the radiobuttons lose their usual mutual exclusiveness.

Example:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let formGroup of groups; let i = index">
      <form *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup">
        <label *ngFor="let mc of codes">
          <input type="radio" [checked]="mc === formGroup.controls.code.value" 
            [formControl]="formGroup.controls.code"> {{mc}}
        </label>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  groups: FormGroup[] = []
  codes: number[] = ['a','b','c']
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    for (let i of [0, 1, 2]) {
      this.groups.push(this.formBuilder.group(
        {code: this.codes[i]}  
      ))
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I replace `[formControl]="formGroup.controls.code"` with `[value]="formGroup.controls.code.value"`, the radiobuttons work as expected, but then, of course, I lose the databinding of the formcontrol.

I edited the code (also in the plunkr) a bit to make clear what is going wrong.

Comment: For what are you using the `name` attribute on `radio-button`? If you don't use it you can just simplify it to: `<input type="radio formControlName="code"> {{mc}}`.

Comment: If I do that, my plunker still does not work. Clicking one radio-item of a group sets all radio items of that group to selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `index` with `i`. And you have to specify value for each of input:

```
<form *ngIf="formGroup" [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <label *ngFor="let mc of codes">
    <input type="radio" name="code-{{i}}" [value]="mc" 
               [formControl]="formGroup.controls.code"> {{mc}}
  </label> 
  {{ formGroup.value | json }}
</form>
```

**[Modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5knykTPAGyCW8htxDaNJ?p=preview)**

Also instead of

```
name="code-{{i}}" [formControl]="formGroup.controls.code"
```

you can just use

```
formControlName="code"
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tJAhAa8ybIT8tFfOueGg?p=preview)**

Comment: You nailed it!, Tx. Although I still do not see exactly why it is working now. Why should both "formControlName" and "[value]" be set, I would have thought that setting formControlName would have the effect of setting the value of the control.